# XSLT equivalent for XML to JSON

Tags: ruby, xml, json, xslt

I have an application where I am parsing an XML document and want to translate it into a JSON document and embed that document directly into MongoDB. Normally going from XML <-> XML I'd use a tool such as XSLT for the translation. Is there currently a decent tool to translate XML -> JSON? Only has to be uni-directional. I won't be translating it back to XML anytime soon. I just want it formatted in a particular state that's embeddable into MongoDB for retrieval and representation to a serializer in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best available tool for translating XML into JSON, either in general or for a particular vocabulary, is XSLT.  Use `method="text"` on your xsl:output element.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using ActiveSupport and Ruby `Hash` as intermediary:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'
Hash.from_xml(xml).to_json
```

Note that it would be pretty easy to manipulate the data when it is a `Hash` if you need to do so.

Also, note that converting XML to a hash can be lossy (when it comes to namespaces and attributes). If you care about this, you might check out other XML parsers (like [Crack](https://github.com/jnunemaker/crack) or [CobraVsMongoose](https://github.com/msievers/cobravsmongoose)), or use XSLT to do the conversion.